# Django: How to get the permissions of a list of users

Tags: django, permissions

So in my application, users can assign basic privs to other users who don't have privs and also make take them away. However, anybody who has these basic privs may not grant or revoke admin privs. So, in my template where I iterate over the list of site_users (for site_user in site_users), how do I get the privs of site_user?

I can only seem to find the privs of the person logged in.

Thanks.
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears others don't have any idea either. So, in my view I am iterating over the users returned and creating a new dict with all the info I need.

Thanks! :)